# What is the difference between client.query and useQuery in Apollo?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo-hooks

In my query, I use a blend of remote and local properties. The local properties have different values depending on:

1. The remote properties
2. The current unix timestamp

The local resolvers computes the local state according to these rules. Now, I face a scenario whereby I need to forego `useQuery` and use Apollo Client's `query` for enhanced flexibility.

Other than structural differences (e.g. `useQuery` accepts two parameters, whereas `client.query` takes only one parameter - the options objects), is it safe to use one over the other?

I identified at least one difference not described in the docs. When I call `client.query` multiple times, the local resolvers are run only once, at the beginning. With `useQuery`, the data always gets recomputed and it has different values (as per #2 above).

Comment: `useQuery`, like the `Query` component and the `graphql` HOC, uses `watchQuery` under the hood. `query` just runs your query and returns the result, while `watchQuery` also subscribes to subsequent changes to the cache.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRearden, but I don't think this explains the difference I found. If the cache is indeed updated after running `client.query`, when I call it the 2nd time it should reflect the cached modified by the resolvers. I understand why `watchQuery` syncs this correctly, but I don't understand why `client.query` doesn't run the resolvers, even if I call it on an interval basis.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with how the more recent versions of `apollo-client` handle local state internally to give a full answer. Just hoping to nudge you onto the right track.