# Apollo GraphQL relay-style cursor pagination doesn't work with cache-first fetch policy

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, relay

why does my example below work fine with fetchPolicy “network-only”, but not with “cache-first”?

I’m using react, apollo-client and “relay” style cursor based paging. pageSize = 50, and I got 64 items in total. Here is my field policy:

```
const typePolicies: TypedTypePolicies = {
  Query: {
    fields: {
      allRetailers: customRelayStylePagination(['filter'])
    }
  }
}
```

customRelayStylePagination is just copy-paste from [relayStylePagination](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/f9f8bef1ce1e66c4f7cdc2f163db9f345f41791c/src/utilities/policies/pagination.ts) to debug.

Here is my function to retrieve ALL retailers:

```
const getAllRetailers = async (showInactiveRetailers: boolean, showInactiveMachines: boolean): Promise<Array<RetailerListItemFragment>> => {
  let myCursor = undefined;
  let hasNextPage = true;
  let result: Array<RetailerListItemFragment> = [];

  const filter = showInactiveRetailers
    ? undefined
    : {
      machineFilter: showInactiveMachines
        ? RetailerMachineFilter.HasActiveOrInactiveMachines
        : RetailerMachineFilter.HasActiveMachines,
    };

  try {
    console.log('start');
    while(hasNextPage) {
      const res: ApolloQueryResult<GetRetailerListQuery> = await apolloClient.query<
        GetRetailerListQuery,
        GetRetailerListQueryVariables
        >({
        variables: {
          cursor: myCursor,
          filter
        },
        query: GET_RETAILER_LIST,
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-first'
      });
      myCursor = res.data.allRetailers?.pageInfo.endCursor;
      hasNextPage = res.data.allRetailers?.pageInfo.hasNextPage || false;
      console.log('hasNext: ' + hasNextPage);
      result = res.data.allRetailers?.edges?.map(c => c.node) || [];
    }
    console.log('done', result);
    return result;

  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

As mentioned this works fine for “network”, but not when using “cache-first”. I get stuck in a infinite loop where hasNextPage is always true. The first GraphQL request returns 50 items. I think the second one returns 50 items too. I observe two read() where both contain 50 items.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Apollo JS can be a pain.  Things to watch out for are duplicate queries.  I've had it before where the original query always fires again so in your situation this would imply an infinite loop.  "nextFetchPolicy" also needs to be considered.  This is the fetch policy always used for ALL SUBSEQUENT queries.  Observe the network tab.  Is it coming back from the server correctly or do you just duplicate queries?

Comment: Hmm ,what do you mean by duplicate query? Do you have an example ? :=)

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens is the following:

- The [`cache-first`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#cache-first) fetch policy means that Apollo will first look into its cache before making a query to the GraphQL server. If it *considers* that all elements are present in the cache, then it will not make a request to the server.
- When using `relayStylePagination()`, [`keyArgs`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/key-args#using-no-arguments) is set to false. In your code, you set it to filter, but it's all the same to Apollo: in both case it will ignore the fact that your cursor variable is different. For this reason, it will consider that all elements are present in the cache and doesn't need to make a request to the server.

I've lost a few hours on this and my understanding is that `relayStylePagination()` simply cannot work with cache-first fetch policy.

---

**EDIT**

I finally got it working by using [`watchQuery()`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient#watchquery) instead of `query()` of the ApolloClient object. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674039/what-is-the-difference-between-client-query-and-usequery-in-apollo#comment103650119_58674039) SO comment, the useQuery hook uses watchQuery under the hood, and useQuery is what's used in Apollo's documentation for cursor-based pagination.

*Note: I'm not using React, that's why I can't use the useQuery hook.*

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
   uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
   headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${githubToken}` },
   defaultOptions: {
      watchQuery: { fetchPolicy: 'cache-first' }
   },
   cache: new InMemoryCache({
      typePolicies: {
         User: {
            fields: { gists: relayStylePagination() }
         }
      }
   })
})

const gistQuery = client.watchQuery({ // doesn't execute the request yet
  query: gqlUserGists,
  variables: { count: 10 }
})

let hasNext = true, cursor = null
while (hasNext) {
  const { data } = await gistQuery.fetchMore({ variables: { cursor } })
  hasNext = data.viewer.gists.pageInfo.hasNextPage
  cursor = data.viewer.gists.pageInfo.endCursor
}
```