# Apollo Graphql relayStylePagination prevents query to refetch on variables change

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

When I use `relayStylePagination` helper funtion in Apollo Client cache type policies, changing the variables passed to the query doesn't call the query again even if I call the `refetch` function manually.
It perfectly does the `fetchMore` behavior and merges the new data.

My cache field looks like this:

```
cache: new InMemoryCache({
      typePolicies: {
        Query: {
          fields: {
            inventories: relayStylePagination(),
          },
        },
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to manually call `refetch` while passing the new variables.
Still have no clue why adding relay type policy prevents triggering `refetch` automatically.

Comment: I have the same issue! Can you please provide an example or explanation of where you called refetch?

Comment: @SeanW
You can do it like this:
 refetch({
        details: {
          sort: {
            sortBy: sortBy,
          },
          filters: handleFilters,
          searchTerm: searchTerm,
        },
        after: 0,
      });
Of course these parameters are based on your query types.

Also one thing that I experienced is that you need to call the refetch in an useEffect It doesn't work if you call it in your callback props and I still don't know why.

Comment: My answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78084689 might help: basically, using `relayStylePagination` and the default fetch policy (cache-first) doesn't seem to be working because of `keyArgs` being set to false, and thus Apollo considering it doesn't need to perform a query to the server.